# Want to print all the elements of Search output list

Tags: java, selenium

```
WebElement dropDown = driver.findElement(By.id("list_bus_suggestion"));

Select suggestionList = new Select(dropDown);

List<WebElement> allOptions = suggestionList.getOptions();

for (int i = 0; i < allOptions.size(); i++) {
    String drop_down_values = allOptions.get(i).getText();

    System.out.println("dropdown values are " + drop_down_values);
}
```

Error is showing in select statement,

> org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "android.widget.ExpandableListView"

Comment: Can you share your HTML? Also, check your imports. Looks like you might be importing a `Select` from a different package.

Comment: import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

Comment: imported this library

Comment: Check your view source code. Your id='list_bus_suggestion' is not a SELECT tag. It is something like android.widget.ExpandableListView. Or edit your questtion with your source code.

Comment: As @SolomonRaja said, this is not a <select> tag could be a ul/li or td tags. Please Include a snippet of your HTML for better responses.

Comment: it has tag android.widget.ExpandableListView